# How to not follow form submit after sending data in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I have a form in my view.

I only want to submit the data, without the rendering of any other template or following the post request to a new URL.

Are there any solutions to this besides structuring the whole thing about AJAX?

EDITED:

I have a multipart form.. 
part 1 submits data to a cache (using AJAX), then I use JQuery to hide that part of the form and show part 2. Part 2 is what submits the main data to a rails controller. That controller action is responsible for pulling the previously cached data and sending a POST request to an API that stores part 1 and part 2 in a database.

What I would like to do:
Have the rails app receive the form data and process the request, then I could use an AJAX request to append data to the page (clearing out the form, and showing the compiled data submitted if the post was successful, and an error message if not).

UPDATE:

I have tried the following and it does nothing when clicked:

```
$('#button').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).submit(); //also tried .send();
    });
```

Comment: We're coming up with some ideas but we're stabbing in the dark a bit. perhaps you can explain what you're trying to achieve and why you think you need this particular solution and then we can figure out how best to help you.

Comment: I submitted an edit that should help explain what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: So you're asking for info to help you build part 1 of the form?

Comment: No, I have the form all worked out.. They are actually all separate forms/pieces of data. The first form is submitted via AJAX, and then it hides itself and shows the second form. The second form is what has the button that posts the data in the form to the controller action. However, I would rather it post the data, then do nothing and just remain on the same page. I think stanc23 might be right, I just haven't gotten around to trying his suggestion yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could either redirect to the same page or maybe do this

```
$('#selector').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
//Do other thing, or maybe nothing
    });
```

Comment: If i prevent default, wont that stop the data from being sent?

Comment: the idea was that you would prevent the default action from happening (i.e. send and redirect) and after preventing default tell it to simply send instead

Comment: I think that is closest to what I am trying to accomplish.. If I call $("#button").send(); for example, it will only send the data?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work or I did something in correctly.. I posted the code I tried under the update section above. Could this have something to do with turbolinks?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller do the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.all { render nothing: true, status: 200 }
end
```